# How do I link epicor shortcut.sysconfig files to records?

Tags: xml, epicorerp

Supposedly in Epicor 10 I can create shortcut.sysconfig files that are sent alongside alert emails to link to specific records in the appropriate tracker.  For example, I can create an alert that sends a shipment notification via email with an attached shortcut.sysconfig file that links to the newly-shipped record.  The problem is that it never actually creates a link to the record -- it only creates a link to the tracker with no record pre-loaded.

The shipment notification alert created has these XML tags:

```
<Shortcut>
 <Company>99999</Company>
  <Plant>MfgSys</Plant>
  <AppServerURL>net.tcp://server.whatever.fakeserver</AppServerURL>
  <DateTime>4/28/2016 1:05:24 PM</DateTime>
  <Originator>Admin</Originator>
  <Process>
   <ProcessID>SRGO1020</ProcessID>
  <Description></Description>
  </Process>
  <RecordIDS KeyFields="SysRowID" KeyFieldsType="System.Guid" TableName="OrderHedList" DataSourceType="OrderHedListDataSet">
   <RecordID>a0b7006e-adc5-4e8a-a011-97f6d9602602</RecordID>
  </RecordIDS>
</Shortcut>
```

The problem in all likelihood lies in the RecordIDS tag but there's almost zero documentation for finding which record this should point to, how it should point to it, and how to change the shortcut.sysconfig template so that it actually populates with the correct record.  Any help?